# installing ios app over a link without hitting the 100 limit

Tags: ios

I've been noticing that some apps are able to distribute their ios apps via a web link (he Humin app is an example) - and do not seem to collect a device id like testflight/ad-hoc distriubtion.  How do they do this?  Do they somehow instananeously add my device to their provisioning profile or are they using some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They must have purchased a enterprise account through which you can share the build without having the need to add the device id to the provisioning profile.

It is used for a enterprise and can also be shared with everyone but that is against their terms and conditions/rules.

you can find the Enterprise account details here
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/